# Visual Studio 2017 - New Project - .NET chooser (Framework/Core) is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I've installed 2.1 Core SDK and then updated VS2017 from 17.5 to 17.7(.3).
For now, .NET chooser is disabled and can't change from Core to Framework, when I choose Core Project.
[image: New Project]
[image: New ASP.NET Core Web Application]

Is there something missing on installing VS tools, on Modifying new version of VS2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've picked ".NET Core" in the first screenshot, on the left.

If you select "Web" instead (the option just above ".NET Core"), you can still choose "ASP.NET Core Web Application" - and at that point you'll be able to switch to ".NET Framework".

I can see both sides here - while it seems somewhat pointless to deny you the option later on, you *have* explicitly said "I want .NET Core" in the first part, so arguably asking you to make the choice again is redundant.

Comment: This used to work this way. You would choose .Net Core ASp.net Web Application template, then in the screen shown above, you could change to .Net Framework. This allowed you to target .Net Framework from an ASP.net Core web application (confusing as all get out). They seem to have reversed this recently.

Comment: It appears that this functionality "returns" if you install the .Net Core SDK 2.1.301!